# Simplifying a fraction

Tags: arithmetic

I'm in doubt on how to simplify $ \left (-\dfrac{1}{243} \right )^{-\frac{2}{3}}$.

I've started with $\left (-\dfrac{1}{9\sqrt{3}} \right )^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ but now I'm stuck because of this minus signal in the main fraction ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take it one step at a time, first getting rid of the negative exponent by taking reciprocals:

$$\begin{align*}
\left(-\frac1{243}\right)^{-\frac23}&=\left(-\frac1{243}\right)^{(-1)\cdot\frac23}\\
&=\left(\left(-\frac1{243}\right)^{-1}\right)^{\frac23}\\
&=(-243)^{2/3}\\
&=\big(-(3^5)\big)^{2/3}\\
&=\big(-(3^5)\big)^{2\cdot\frac13}\\
&=\left(\big(-(3^5)\big)^2\right)^{1/3}\\
&=\left(3^{10}\right)^{1/3}\\
&=3^{10/3}\\
&=3^{3+\frac13}\\
&=3^3\cdot3^{1/3}\\
&=27\sqrt[3]3\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: What happened to the minus sign in the first step? To me, the interesting part of this question is how a fractional power of a negative number *should* be handled.

Comment: We harbor the same general feeling, robjohn.

Comment: @robjohn: Beats me; I apparently concentrated so hard on the reciprocal that I forgot the minus sign altogether.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\left( -\frac{1}{243} \right)^{-\frac{2}{3}} = (-243)^\frac{2}{3} = \sqrt[3]{(-243)^2} = 27\sqrt[3]{3}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(-{1\over 243}\right)^{-2/3} = {\left(3^5\right)^{-2/3}} = 3^{10/3} = 27\root{3}\of 3$$

You ditch the - because of the even power.  This is dangerous and dicey tho' because of certain bad behavior between fractional powers and negative numbers.

Comment: it's dangerous, so why are you doing it anyway?

Comment: It is likely what your book expects you to do.  The answer of experimentX shows you where the danger lurks.

Comment: Since the context is likely the real domain, this danger is suppressed.

Comment: Here is another pernicious peril.  Notice that $(-1)^{1/3} = (-1)^{2/6} = (1)^{1/6} = 1.$   Oops.

Comment: you clearly missed my point. if it's so dangerous, at the very least you should mathematically explain why you can do it anyway. saying it's dangerous is easy - now explain why you can do it anyway.

Comment: Note the tag homework. Sometimes problem-writers for books at this level play fast and loose.

Comment: That doesn't mean /you/ should. The point of this site is to clarify what regular texts don't.